# Как правильно сделать так чтобы submit не отправлялся при определённых условиях через js?

Tags: javascript, form, submit

Как правильно сделать так чтобы  submit не отправлялся при определённых условиях через js?

Делаю вот так но страница всё равно перезагружается даже если условие проходит

```
        if(!validtitle || !validtext){
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: `})` в конце кода подсказывает, что у вас `addEventListener('submit'`, а не `onsubmit`... а return false выключает только on-события... для addEventListener нужен `event.preventDefault();` Угадал?)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("reservation").disabled = false;
```

document.getElementById("reservation").disabled = true;